# How do I set the background (window) for a tableview to an image?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I have set the background colour of my UITableView to clear so that I can see the UIWindow.  But I want to change the image presented (from background.png), depending on my selection.  An example would be:
 If (selection = 'blue') then image = bluesky.png
 if (selection = 'green') then image = 'greengrass.png

thx,
wes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the background clear and putting an image behind it, you can set the tableview's background color using an image

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greengrass.png"]];
```

Comment: The way that I finally got working was to set the delegate window bacgkground independently of the UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Just change the background image based on the selection, assuming your controller is `UITableViewController` or implements the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSString *imageName = @"default.png";
     switch (indexPath.row) {
       case ...: // fill correct imageName based on selection
     }

     self.myBackgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Btw - this also assumes you have an IBOutlet or something for your background image.